# how to input all data first, then give all output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, class

i'm new to programming, and i need your help on my problem.

i made a code, a loop input like this:

```
for x in range (2):
    name = input('name   : ')
    age = input('age    : ')

    print()

    print('name', name)
    print('age', age)

    print('---------------')
```

the output is like this.

```
name   : garox
age    : 29

name garox
age 29
---------------
name   : supri
age    : 16

name supri
age 16
---------------
```

i want the output to be separated from each inputs, like this:

```
---  input ---
name   : garox
age    : 29

name   : supri
age    : 16

--- output ----
name garox
age 29

name supri
age 16
```

so i want to input all data first, then output comes after i finished all inputs.

also using loop, not doing 'print' one by one.
is it possible? if so, how should i do that?

thanks in advance.

---

thanks for your answers ! that really helps me to understand it better.

i tried to put it inside a class. but i got this error:

```
    Dataa.looop(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

here's how i arrange the code.

```
class Dataa():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def looop (self):
        list = []

        for x in range(2):
            name = input('name   : ')
            age = input('age    : ')
            list.append({'name': name, 'age': age})

        for input in list:
            print('name', input['name'])
            print('age', input['age'])
            print('---------------')

Dataa.looop(self)
```

how do i call the loop def, so i can make the inputs?

Comment: Use a `list`, and `append` the `data` that is read from the user to the `list`. Perhaps put the `data` into`tuple` and `append` to list like `name = input('..'); age = input('''.'); details.append((name, age))`. And after you have added all the details, you could iterate through the details and then just output them

Comment: Accumulate the data in a container to use it after the for loop terminates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with adding input strings to a list:

```
persons=[]
print("-----input------")
for x in range (2):
    name = input('name   : ')
    age = input('age    : ')

    persons.append([name,age])

print('--------output-------')
for x in persons:
    print("name:",x[0])
    print("age:", x[1])
```

Result:

```
-----input------
name   : name1
age    : 30
name   : name2
age    : 30

--------output-------
name: name1
age: 30
name: name2
age: 30
```

Comment: You can use unpacking to make the second loop simpler: `for name, age in persons:` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list that will store each input as a dictionary with two keys: name and age.

Then you create two `for` loops : The first one to store the inputs and the second one to print data. I think this approach is better because you can use it to add as many as you want.

```
persons = []

for x in range (2):
    name = input('name   : ')
    age = input('age    : ')
    country = input('country    : ')
    persons.append({'name': name, 'age': age, 'country': country})

for input in persons:
    print('name', input['name'])
    print('age', input['age'])
    print('country', input['country'])
    print('---------------')
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
name : john
age : 27
name : david
age : 17
name john
age 27
----------------
name david
age 17
----------------
```

Comment: don't use `list` as an identifier, it will shadow the builtin `list` type.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)